# Pandas: Reading TSV into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file-io

I'm using Python 2.7 and have a TSV formatted as follows (368 rows × 3 columns):

```
date    dayOfWeek    pageviews
2016    4            3920
...
```

I have a Jupyter notebook saved in the same location as the TSV.  I'm running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_table('query_explorer.tsv')
```

I get back a dataframe that's 736 rows × 3 columns and filled with NaNs.  It's interesting too, because I should have only 368 rows (exactly half of what I do have).

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have blank lines between the rows?

Comment: @DYZ Just checked, don't think so :(

Comment: Do you have blank lines at the end of the file, then? Check the number of _lines_ (not _rows_) in your TSV file.

Comment: @DYZ I just ran "wc -l query_explorer.tsv" and got back 369 which is what I expected...

Comment: Where are the NaNs in your DataFrame? At the end or scattered around?

Comment: can you show output with few lines of your table

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue if file is truly a **t**ab-**s**eparated **v**alues (tsv) file.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
pd.read_table('query_explorer.tsv',delim_whitespace=True,header=0)
```

Comment: Same result as before, unfortunately

Comment: can you share the link to the file or subset of it?

Answer (score 1):

In `csv` files comma is the separator. For `tsv` files, the tab character will separate each field. `pandas` according to separator can recognize and separate columns.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('query_explorer.tsv',sep="\t")
```

Comment: Please edit the answer to include an explanation that covers why this will work.

Comment: @JasonAller  Done.